# Error ssh: connect to host 333 port 22: Invalid argument

Tags: shell, ssh, scp

I try to transfer the "test" folder to another server using command shell script `scp`, then I get an error like:

```
ssh: connect to host 333 port 22: Invalid argument
lost connection
```

my script:

```
scp /test_web/test ssh -i example.pem root@222.111.222.111 -p 333:/web
```

I'm just learning about shell script, I don't know if there's a syntax wrong or not, I'm very grateful if you can help solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is

```
scp -P 333 -i example.pem /test_web/test root@222.111.222.111:/web
```

For most programs you can find a man page with synopsis through `man {command name}`.

For example: `man scp`

If you encounter further issues, check if you are able to use ssh with root at all. Sometimes root is not permitted to connect via ssh.

Comment: I've done like that, but an error appears "Permission denied (publickey). lost connection"  @b2f